# How do I sort a json using a time stamp field within the json file in Postman?

Tags: json, postman, postman-testcase

I am new to Postman, I have a API call which gives me the output as a json. In the "Test", I get the JSON by `"bodyData = JSON.parse(responseBody);"`

The JSON file has got timestamp fields example `"executedDate": "2020-11-26T09:45:27.000Z"`. I would need help in sorting the JSON file in descending order based on the `executedDate` field.

```
 {
   "dataflowJobs": [
    {
        "createdDate": "2020-11-26T09:45:03.000Z",
        "duration": 48,
        "executedDate": "2020-11-26T09:45:27.000Z",
        "id": "03C2w000002Urb1EAC",
        "jobType": "user",
        "label": "Dataflow_2",
        "progress": 1.0,
        "startDate": "2020-11-26T09:45:03.000Z",
        "status": "Success",
        "type": "dataflowjob",
        "url": "/services/data/v47.0/wave/dataflowjobs/03C2w000002Urb1EAC"
    },
    {
        "createdDate": "2020-11-26T09:45:01.000Z",
        "duration": 34,
        "executedDate": "2020-11-26T09:45:02.000Z",
        "id": "03C2w000002UracEAC",
        "jobType": "user",
        "label": "Adv_Dataflow_Exercises",
        "progress": 1.0,
        "startDate": "2020-11-26T09:45:01.000Z",
        "status": "Success",
        "type": "dataflowjob",
        "url": "/services/data/v47.0/wave/dataflowjobs/03C2w000002UracEAC"
    },        {
        "createdDate": "2020-11-20T09:45:01.000Z",
        "duration": 58,
        "id": "0eP2w000000MhszEAC",
        "jobType": "recipe",
        "label": "Feb_and_Jan_S2_Modified_Recipe2_recipe",
        "progress": 1.0,
        "startDate": "2020-11-20T09:45:01.000Z",
        "status": "Success",
        "type": "dataflowjob",
        "url": "/services/data/v47.0/wave/dataflowjobs/0eP2w000000MhszEAC"
    }
],
"url": "/services/data/v47.0/wave/dataflowjobs"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let moment = require('moment')


let jsonData = pm.response.json()

console.log(jsonData.dataflowJobs.sort(function (a, b) { return moment(b.executedDate).diff(moment(a.executedDate), "seconds") }))
```

This will sort according to executed time , if there is no executed time it will be at the top

Comment: Thank you PDHide for the response. The sorting works but I see the sorted result in the console only. The actual body response is not sorted. Is there a way to do the sort the response body? 

I am trying to do some checks after the response body is sorted.

Comment: Just assign it to variable you want !

Comment: jsonData = jsonData.dataflowjobs bla bla

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign thank you